# Mouse and video integration with VMware Tools doesn't work on cloned VMs

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vmware-tools

When I clone a virtual machine from a template that already has Tools installed the mouse integration and better resolution of the console don't work. vCenter recognizes that Tools is installed.

Why is that?

Comment: dang I had this problem a couple weeks ago, how did you create the template.  There are few different ways to do this and one of them isn't right and I can't figure out which one it is.  What works for me is clone a running maching to template then deploy from template.  This process will run sysprep automatically during the deployment and the vmtools will work fine.

Comment: That's basically what I did. I created a VM with some standard programs installed (including tools) and Windows updates then turned it into a template.